# io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestEncoder$ErrorDataEncoderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: testing, karate

Can you please help me to solve out this issue (I'm getting an error):

```
 Data:
    {
     "file":"bird.jpeg"
      }

    My Graphql query:
    mutation UpdateProfilePicture ($file: Upload!) {
        singleUpload(file: $file){
        done
    }
   }
```

Feature file:

```
Feature: get parent players

    Background:
    * url baseUrl
    Scenario: get parent players details

    * def result = call read(loginPath)
    * def accessToken = result.accessToken
    * print "Access Token : ", accessToken
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken

    Given def query = read(gqlBase +'updateProfilePicture.gql')
    And request { query: '#(query)'}
    * multipart file file = {read:'bird.jpeg', filename:'bird.jpeg',Content-type:'image/jpeg'}
    When method post
    Then status 200
    * print 'response: ', response.data
```

When I tried to upload a picture, getting below error:

> io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestEncoder$ErrorDataEncoderException:java.io.FileNotFoundException]

Comment: I wonder if you need to do something different for binary / multipart when it comes to graphql. if you can find a public example, that will help. or request you to do some research to help the community. or provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @Peter Thomas